# ISE Design suite

Tags: fpga, ise

im extremely new to ISE design suite. In fact, im waiting for my windows PC to arrive so i can actually download it.
But i wanted to ask, if i wrote some VHDL for a full adder logic circuit using 2 half adders and an OR gate, this gives me the first image.

Is the second image how this circuit would actually be implemented using the existing hardware on an FPGA?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Depends on the FPGA.

Comment: Please provide a link to the source of these images.

Comment: Also, you cut off the bottom part of the top image.

Comment: Do you get how a [LUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table#Hardware_LUTs) lets you implement an arbitrary N-input, 1-output combinatorial logic block? (N  depends on what kind of FPGA you have)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxXTy3PXLVs&list=PLZv8x7uxq5XY-IQfQFb6mC6OXzz0h8ceF&index=21

Comment: I have taken those images from that video

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do not use schematic design - use Verilog or VHDL from day one.  Which you pick matters less than that you pick one of the two, as they can do about the same things but have different philosophy of expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with some small modifications depending on exactly which FPGA you use.

The circuit you show is just combinational logic, and FPGAs use look-up tables (LUTs) to implement combinational logic. The bottom image just adds buffers for the three input signals (ibuf) and for the two output signals (obuf).